# Xcode 7. Simulators full reset

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode7, reset

Most iOS version are downloaded, but all ios Version (iOS 8.x, iOS 9.x, etc  doesn't appear in the dropdown on Xcode.
How to reset this?  (I know I can re-add manually using "Devices, Add", but i'm sure it's a way to just reset all, and have Xcode to offer redownload the sim.)

EDIT: The iOS I need to redownload, are the one that are ALREADY downloaded. – Franck

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get my answer from the 'snapshot' git. (Fastlane)

> reset_simulators is removing all simulators and create new one only
>   for the latest iOS version. If you want to recreate simulators for
>   other versions you have to provide the list of the versions after the
>   --ios argument, e.g.
>
> snapshot reset_simulators --ios 8.3,8.4,9.0,9.1

Work perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode go to *Window > Devices* and see if you have duplicates in the list of devices there.

You can delete devices here by selecting one and using the delete key. After deleting you will see the related download as not started in the *Downloads* window. Xcode will offer to re-download eventually or you can start the download manually.

Comment: Forgot about this second option - added this answer just to be complete

Answer (score 0):

Click here to restart download ...
[image]

But if you really want to re-download, you can just delete the simulators and Xcode will offer to re-download.
Go to `/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes` and delete the files/bundles there

Comment: The iOS I need to redownload, are the one that are ALREADY downloaded.

Comment: In that case something is wrong with your saved simulators. Deleting will probably fix this.  With Xcode 6.x I had an issue with duplicated Simulators - deleting fixed that as well.

Comment: How to delete it ? :)

Comment: See my edited answer. Just go to /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes and delete the .simruntime bundles.

Comment: Sorry, Missed this.  No /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtime folder. (just a folder "/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices")

I've try a lot of things, including, "snapshot reset_simulators".  Possible that this have delete this folder.  :(

Comment: I'm sure there is. You have been looking in your user folder, not root. The one you mentioned is ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices (mind the ~). That is in your user folder and not the one I'm talking about

Comment: Yes, thanks!   I can now delete sim, and re-download!   But, even if I delete it, it was still not appear in the Xcode dropdown (first image in my question)